# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.CLIENT' with unique index '@KOD_CLIENT'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This is the code:

```
string CLIENT = "declare @KOD VARCHAR(10) 
                 set   @KOD = 'K' + (SELECT CAST(MAX(SUBSTRING(KOD,3,4)) + 1 as VARCHAR(7)) KOD
                 FROM  CLIENT 
                 WHERE INTERNET='TABLET')";
```

The column KOD increment by 1, example K1, K2, K3, when it reaches K10 and I try to add a row it shows me this problem.

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.CLIENT' with unique
>   index '@KOD_CLIENT'.

The DataType of column KOD is varchar(10)

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @GarethD , when I try to add a row on table CLIENT, the column KOD gives me an error. How to fix this code? I believe you know what that code does that I've wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(MAX(SUBSTRING(KOD,3,4)) + 1 as VARCHAR(7))
```

...uses `MAX` on the string, which since string sort alphabetically means `2` is greater than `10`. This will seriously mess up your numbering scheme, since with 2 and 10 in the table, the next number you will generate is 3.

What you want is to cast first and do `MAX` on the integer;

```
SELECT CAST(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(KOD,3,4) AS INT)) + 1 AS VARCHAR(7))
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to show the difference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd2b3/3).

As a side note, generating your own sequential IDs in the database is very seldom a good idea, since simultaneous writes can conflict and prevent the insert from succeeding. You may want to rethink the number generation and base it on - for example - an auto increment column.

Comment: It still give me the same error. :/ But when I remove `'K' + ` from the code it works. Any idea why?

Comment: @aldoblack If you only have a single character prefix, you need to change the substring to `SUBSTRING(2,4)`, since you're cutting away 2 characters before the cast. If you're still getting an error, could you post an sqlfiddle with a more realistic example that shows the failure?

Comment: Yes, I had to do `SUBSTRING(2,4)` . Thank You. It works now. :D